# How do I find the "effective" yaw, pitch and roll from a rotated Inertial Measurement Unit?

Tags: rotations

Consider a right-hand coordinate system, N with basisvectors $\{\hat{x_N},\hat{y_N},\hat{z_N}\}$ where:

- the x-axis is pointing north
- the y-axis is pointing east

Consider an airplane with a right-hand coordinate system, B with basis vectors $\{\hat{x_B},\hat{y_B},\hat{z_B}\}$ where:

- the x-axis is pointing towards the nose of the plane
- the y-axis is pointing towards the right wing

Looking at an online [Euler Angle Visualization Tool](https://danceswithcode.net/engineeringnotes/rotations_in_3d/demo3D/rotations_in_3d_tool.html)
it seems that the definition of roll, pitch and yaw of the plane is ?:

- the N basisvectors are first rotated yaw around the the z-axis
- the new basisvectors are rotated pitch around the new y-axis
- the new basisvectors are rotated roll around the new x-axis and the result is the B basis vectors:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} \hat{x_B} \\ \hat{y_B} \\ \hat{z_B} \end{bmatrix}
=R_{BN}*\begin{bmatrix} \hat{x_N} \\ \hat{y_N} \\ \hat{z_N} \end{bmatrix}
$$
where
$$
R_{BN}=RX_{BN}(roll)*RY_{BN}(pitch)*RZ_{BN}(yaw)
$$
[image]

I find that
$$
RZ_{BN} = RZ^T
$$
$$
RY_{BN} = RY^T
$$
$$
RX_{BN} = RX^T
$$
$$
R=RZ*RY*RX=R_{BN}^T
$$
where RX, RY RZ and R are the [standard rotation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) used to convert a position from a rotated coordinate system to an unrotated:
[image]
Is this correct?

Next let us assume that roll, pitch and yaw is measured by an instrument (an Inertial Measurement Unit).
We introduce a coordinate system for the instrument, I with basisvectors $\{\hat{x_I},\hat{y_I},\hat{z_I}\}$.

The instrument is rotated wrt to the airplane:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} \hat{x_I} \\ \hat{y_I} \\ \hat{z_I} \end{bmatrix}
=R_{IB}*\begin{bmatrix} \hat{x_B} \\ \hat{y_B} \\ \hat{z_B} \end{bmatrix}
$$

Given a known $R_{IB}$ and a measurement from the instrument: $(yaw_i, pitch_i,roll_i)$ how can I find $(yaw, pitch,roll)$ of the airplane?

Comment: $$R_{IN} = RX_{IN}(roll_i) * RY_{IN}(pitch_i) * RZ_{IN}(yaw_i)$$
$$R_{BN} = R_{IN} * R_{IB}^T$$
$$pitch = \arcsin(-R_{BN}(2, 0))$$
$$roll = \arctan2(R_{BN}(2, 1), R_{BN}(2, 2))$$
$$yaw = \arctan2(R_{BN}(1, 0), R_{BN}(0, 0))$$

Comment: @rumathe: Should it not be: $roll=arctan2(R(2,1),R(2,2)) = arctan2(R_{BN}(1,2),R_{BN}(2,2))$?

Comment: You right, mistypo.